# Erro Eclipse #{component.valid} "valid cannot be resolved as a member of component"

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Eclipse da warning em #{component.valid} no SryleClass, Com obs que o imputText está dentro de um Composite Component.

```
<div class="labelledInput">
        <p:inputText id="txtPesqLot" ...
            styleClass="labelledInput-input #{component.valid?'':'validation-failed'}"/> 
</div>
```

Comment: ele não está achando o atributo valid dentro de component...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está com versões mais velhas do Eclipse como no meu caso. há 2 soluções que resolveu. a primeira é trocar  #{component.valid} por
 #{UIComponent.valid} .

Segunda solução :[image: Configuração]